# What is the initial and rigorous definition of state function $\psi$ in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, fourier-transform, probability, born-rule

Is the
$$
    P_{a\le x\le b} (t) = \int\limits_a^b d x\,|\psi(x)|^2 \, 
$$
and
$$
    P_{a\le p\le b} (t) = \int\limits_a^b d p\,|\psi(p)|^2 \, 
$$
results or axiomatic definitions?

---

Sorry if the question is asked before.

Comment: Suggestion to the post (v2): Replace the word _state function_ with _wave function._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, the wave function is the probability amplitude. Thus, the probability of finding the particle at point $x=x'$ is the wave function squared, and the probability of finding it in the interval $[a,b]$ is given by the integral of the wave function squared over this region. This rule (that probability equals wave function squared) is known as the **Born rule**, and follows from the *definition* of the wave function.

Of course, the question arises of why the wave function is the probability amplitude. This is a deep question--an excellent discussion can be [found here on Sean Carroll's blog.](http://www.preposterousuniverse.com/blog/2014/07/24/why-probability-in-quantum-mechanics-is-given-by-the-wave-function-squared/)

Answer (score 1):

Neither is the definition.

A "state" in quantum mechanics means pretty much the same (at an abstract level) as it does everywhere else in physics and, more generally, in systems theory. It is a quantity - where "quantity" is almost always a collection of numbers - in quantum mechanics it is most often a countably infinite collection of complex numbers, but sometimes a finite collection of them will do. Moreover, it is a quantity that specifies a system unambiguously *i.e.*:

1. The state at any given time tells you *everything* that can in principle be found experimentally out about the system at that time;
2. It follows an "equation of motion" or "equation of evolution" that tells you unambiguously how the state at any time can be derived from the state at any other time. In quantum mechanics, this is the Schrödinger equation.

There are two further behaviors of the notion of state "peculiar" to quantum mechanics:

1. The above two points only hold true *between measurements*. At measurement, the state is irreversibly changed as it becomes a random eigenvector of an operator modelling the measurement $\hat{A}$, with the probability that the eigenvector $\vec{\psi}_{\hat{A}\,n}$ is the one output from the measurement when the state $\vec{\psi}$ prevails is $|\langle\vec{\psi}_{\hat{A}\,n}|\vec{\psi}\rangle|^2$;
2. At the same time, the measurement returns the real eigenvalue $\lambda_n$ corresponding to $\vec{\psi}_{\hat{A}\,n}$ as the result of the measurement. The link between state and experiment in quantum mechanics, therefore, is that system states only define the statistics of *ensembles of systems with the same quantum state* - each instance within that ensemble yields measurements that are random variables conforming to those statistics. Quantum states only let us calculate probability distributions, whereas classical states tells us exactly what a measurement will be. The $n^{th}$ moment of the probability distribution of the measurement, when the measurement observable is $\hat{A}$ and state $\vec{\psi}$ prevails is $\left<\vec{\psi}\left|\hat{A}^n\right|\vec{\psi}\right>$.

In both classical *linear* physics and quantum physics, states can be construed as vectors in a Hilbert space: in classical physics the Hilbert space is some usually some finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. The inner product of the Hilbert space allows one to decompose linear classical and quantum states into eigenfunctions, although in linear classical systems only eigenfunctions of the time evolution operator are important because they simplify calculations: a system's behavior when a state prevails is the sum of the behaviors when the state is resolved into a superposition of eigenfunctions. In quantum mechanics, the inner product plays a much more important role: it is central in the calculation of probability densities of measurements when a quantum state prevails.

It's helpful to compare a simple quantum system and a classical one in this respect. Let's consider a classical and quantum harmonic oscillator. The classical one dimensional HO has a state vector:

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}x\\p\end{array}\right)$$

where $x$ is the oscillator's position and $p$ its momentum. These two real numbers at any one time let us compute $x$ and $p$ at any other time, because the equation of evolution is:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \left(\begin{array}{cc}x\\p\end{array}\right)= \left(\begin{array}{cc}0&-1\\1&0\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}x\\p\end{array}\right)$$

whose unique solution is:

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}x(t)\\p(t)\end{array}\right)=\exp\left(t\,\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&-1\\1&0\end{array}\right)\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}x(0)\\p(0)\end{array}\right)$$

The quantum harmonic oscillator's state lives in a Hilbert space of countably infinite dimension ("the" unique, separable Hilbert space of dimension $\aleph_0$). One possible basis for this state space is the set of energy eigenstates. As a column vector, we would represent the first eigenstate above the ground state as:

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}0\\1\\0\\0\\\vdots\end{array}\right)$$

and the general quantum state is represented countably infinite superposition weights:

$$\psi=\left(\begin{array}{cc}\psi_0\\\psi_1\\\psi_2\\\psi_3\\\vdots\end{array}\right)$$

and the state vector's evolution equation - the Schrödinger equation - is:

$$i\,\hbar\,\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \psi= E_0\,\left(\begin{array}{cccc}\frac{1}{2}&0&0&\cdots\\0&\frac{3}{2}&0&\cdots\\0&0&\frac{5}{2}&\cdots\\&&\vdots&\end{array}\right)\,\psi$$

Now this probably doesn't look very much like the Schrödinger equation or quantum "state" you've studied so far. This is because we can put the quantum state into different co-ordinates. We can choose the basis for the Hilbert space to be the eigenvectors of the observable we are interested in - for example, the position or momentum observable. Here's where things get a little bit complicated, because

*Not all observables have a discrete spectrum*

The position observable, in the energy eigenstate basis above, is a discrete, countably infinite dimensional square matrix. But its spectrum of possible eigenvalues is the *whole real line*. So when we resolve any state expressed as the discrete superposition weights $\psi_0,\,\psi_1,\,\cdots$ of the energy eigenstates into superposition weights, we seemingly get uncountably infinitely many of them, we get a complex-valued function of the probability amplitude $\psi(x)$ to make a measurement with value $x\in\mathbb{R}$ using the position observable. It's the same principle: for the energy eigenstate basis, the superposition weight $\psi_n$ is the probability amplitude for the energy to be measured at the $n^{th}$ excited level $(n+\frac{1}{2})\,E_0$. Moreover, our continuous function doesn't really tell us an uncountably infinite number of probability amplitudes: the state $\psi(x)$ lives in $\mathbf{L}^2(\mathbb{R})$, the space of square Lebesgue integrable, complex valued functions of one real variable (actually, the points are equivalence classes of functions, modulo equality almost everywhere, but don't get too distracted by this). And this space has only a countably infinite number of degrees of freedom. It can be spanned by the energy eigenvectors; the same states that we studied above, but now they look like complex valued functions $\psi_n(x)$ in the new position co-ordinates

It's a similar story for the momentum co-ordinates. When we use momentum co-ordinates, we simply write the quantum state as a superposition of the momentum eigenstates. Like the position observable, the momentum observable has a continuous spectrum, running over $\mathbb{R}$. In position co-ordinates, the momentum observable is $-i\,\hbar\,\partial_x$ and we then need to find co-ordinates that make this operator a simple multiplication operator, so that we have $\psi(p) \mapsto p\,\psi(p)$ instead of $\psi(x)\mapsto -i\,\hbar\,\partial_x\,\psi(x)$. The Fourier transform converts differentiation to multiplication, so that's why it converts position to momentum representations.